# Reading/ Writing from/to a file

Tags: c++

I am working on an OOP project and I need to write into a file and I faced a problem that each time I do it the file is over written with only one object. How can I make it to write data of all the objects? I tried this but didnt work.

```
virtual void save(ofstream outfile) = 0;`// the base class

void AND2::save(ofstream outf) //derived
{
    outf.open("test.txt");
    outf << Component::getype() << " ";
    outf<< Component::getid() << " ";
    outf << Component:: graphicsinfomration().x1 << " ";
    outf<< Component::graphicsinfomration().x2 << " ";
    outf << graphicsinfomration().y1 << " ";
    outf << graphicsinfomration().y2 << " ";
    outf << endl;
    outf.close();
}
else          
{
    ofstream outf;
    for (int i = 0; i < (pApp->getcompcount()); i++)
    {
        //ask user to enter text name
        c[i]->save( outf);
    }
    pOut->ClearStatusBar();
}
```

Comment: Is this where we assume you're executing this repeatedly in a *loop* ? And I'm curious how you managed to pass that output file stream *by value*, which shouldn't even be possible, to your function? Regardless, have the *caller* send an already-open filestream *by reference* to your writer proc, which should be doing just that, and only that.

Comment: Streams should be passed by reference.  Usually passing by copy generates error messages.

Comment: Your save function just overwrites the same file each time. You need to open it and seek to the end to append data to it, e.g. `outf.open("test.txt", std::ofstream::out | std::ofstream::app);`.

Comment: This is not your real code. Streams cannot be copied. Present your [MCVE].

Comment: I know about that streams can not be copied i just forgot to write it here, the main problem  was with the overwriting, @JonathanPotter I think that's what iam looking for. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you're opening the file again and again you overwrite the contents again and again.

You probably want to open the stream outside the for loop once and pass it by reference.